# Whitelist Rejection in MeteorJs [PhoneGap]

Tags: ios, mongodb, cordova, meteor

i have put access origin for specific url can access like below:

error shows:

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://graph.facebook.com/1009003465778334/picture?type=large&

<access origin="*.facebook.com/*">
```

i'm still wonder where is the problem ?

Comment: Any console output? And which iOS version do you use? Did it work under iOS 8? ... some more information please!!

You know ATS? Apple Transport Security?

Comment: my target development is 7.0 ? can you show me which one you ask ?

Comment: `<access origin="*.facebook.*" />` you tried that?

Comment: yeah, i have followed that App Transport Security info, i also do and configure that file .plist

Comment: oke, let me try once

Comment: it still persist, same error shows

Comment: `<access origin="*" />` does this work than?

Comment: Post the domain which exactly you're sending the request to.

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/

Comment: Try this in your `config.xml` `<allow-navigation href="*://*.facebook.com/*" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fixed!

```
<access origin="*://graph.facebook.com/*" />
<access origin="*://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*" />
```